# Check if an Angular directive exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We're doing a lot of work around dynamic directives in our Angular project, and one thing that came up as a nice-to-have was a way to have a generic directive that can list many different types of similar objects (e.g., messages, users, comments, etc.), by delegating to specific directives based on the objects' types.

We call this directive, `object-list` and it will hopefully delegate to a number of different directives, if we can get it working properly.

The main issue we need to tackle is whether or not a directive that this `object-list` directive has been provided exists in our system. The way we've been checking this is by issuing a `$compile` against the target directive, linking it to a scope, and checking its HTML contents (e.g., `var tmpElement = $compile('<div my-message'></div>')(scope);`). This seems to work when the template for the target directive is referenced by the `template` option, but when we instead try to point to a `templateUrl`, the HTML contents are empty.

Here's a Plunker, with the `templateUrl` approach in place (not working). You can comment it out and uncomment the `template` line to see the alert show up.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wD4ZspbGSo68v4eRViTp

Is there another way to check the existence of a directive? I'll admit, this does seem a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `$injector.has` to check if a provider or instance exists.

```
app.directive('objectList', function ($compile, $injector) {
  return {
    template: 'OK',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var exist = $injector.has('myMessageDirective');
      ...
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Buu. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this works. The documentation for the `$injector.has()` method states it's only for service lookups. Further, trying it on my Plunker (updated here http://plnkr.co/edit/owHeruUXmfxFSE1klv7S) fails to give me the results I'm looking for.

Comment: It should be `$injector.has('myMessageDirective')`, not `$injector.has('myMessage')`.  (Why? Because the $compile service adds the "Directive" suffix when registering any directive.)   Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/n1XX6cgvZ4o6eVGhj4aO?p=preview

Comment: Aah, I see now. Thanks, Buu!

Comment: You can use it for checking component existence (Angular 1.5+), too.