# How to check if a component exists in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

http://embed.plnkr.co/oGlcQSOM2vFcDEKP7thV/

`$injector.has('myMessageDirective')` returns true, while `$injector.has('myMessageComponent')` does not

Is anyone struggling with this or has a solution? My "fear" is that my components might not be found in future updates because of the directive check.

Follow up question to: [Check if an Angular directive exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753081/check-if-an-angular-directive-exists/)

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, a component is registered as a directive, so 'Directive' suffix is indeed needed.

Check 'has' method of $injector object:

```
return {
  invoke: invoke,
  instantiate: instantiate,
  get: getService,
  annotate: createInjector.$$annotate,
  has: function(name) {
    return providerCache.hasOwnProperty(name + providerSuffix) || cache.hasOwnProperty(name);
  }
};
```

You can debug it and see that all components (inside cache object) are registered as directives. There is no 'Component' suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I think, simplest way is to add an `id` attribute to directive's/component's container, then check if element with this `id` exist.

Comment: I'd like to avoid checking via the DOM. Also in my context, I do $compile a component, thus I need to know if I can create a specific component or not.